# fibonacci numbers from 0 to n

Tags: c++, fibonacci

I tried to make a program that puts out all Fibonacci numbers from 0 to the number you enter, but there is a mistake in it and I don't find it... it compiles. It would be really helpful if someone can tell me where my fault is ;). It is printing endless 0000

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
int n,erste = 0,zweite = 1,neu = 0;
std::cout << "Enter N  ";
std::cin >> n;


for( int s = 0 ;s < n; s++ )
 {

 if(s <= 1)
    s = neu;
   else{
    neu = erste + zweite;
    erste = zweite;
    zweite = neu;
   }

   std::cout << neu << "  ";

  }}
```

Comment: The very least you could do is explain the error that you are having.

Comment: And BTW, it is the first time that someone tells that the Fibonacci series starts at `0`.

Comment: @SJuan76 Is not that rare, if you define F_0 = 0, F_1 = 1 as the starting terms, you get nice properties like F_k being a multiple of 5 whenever k is a multiple of 5.

Comment: @SJuan76 It's not rare at all.

Answer (score 4):

```
new = 0;
for( int s = 0 ;s < n; s++ )
  if(s <= 1)
    s = neu;
```

At every iteration you are setting the index to 0. No wonder the loop does not end.

As a rule of thumb, avoid assigning a value to the variant variable of a `for` (do not forget to change the values if it is a `while`, though).

Comment: Oh, and learn to use a debugger (even the poor man`s debugger, prints to console).

Comment: in the for statment? or where?

Comment: if you use a `for` loop, do not change the value of the variable inside the loop (if you need to, use a `while` loop)

Answer (score 1):

If s <= 1, you assign 0 to s. Since s is initialized to zero and is the loop counter, it will always be zero and the loop will be infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Where the fault is is easy to tell. I'm struggling to understand *why* you made the mistake you did. But anyway this is better, at least it won't loop forever.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
int n,erste = 0,zweite = 1,neu = 0;
std::cout << "Enter N  ";
std::cin >> n;

for( int s = 0 ;s < n; s++ )
 {

    neu = erste + zweite;
    erste = zweite;
    zweite = neu;

   std::cout << neu << "  ";

  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your solution; my fault is probally coming from the fact that i want n as a number and i want all fibonacci numbers to this number for exemple if i enter the number 12 i want 0 0 1 1 2 5 7

Comment: OK that's great, but it's not what your code does. You need a `while` loop, and you need to loop until the fibonacci number is bigger than the number entered. BTW the fibonacci sequence does not begin with two zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Most part of what you're doing there makes no sense. Take a look on a correct code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "1 ";
    if (n >= 2)
        cout << "1 ";

    for (int i = 3; i <= n; ++i) {
        a = b;
        b = c;
        c += a;
        cout << c << ' ';
    }
}
```